# Which is better for counting frequency of elements in array hashing or unordered_map

Tags: c++, arrays, hash, counting, unordered-map

For frequency counting, which is better hashing or unordered_map ?
Also is there any limit size of hashing array ?

Sometimes I face errors while using hashing (seg. fault)
If there is better approach please let me know.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by hashing. ```unordered_map``` is a hash map. If you built your own, please show your code so that we can fix it

Comment: Depends what you are counting. If you are counting items with limited size (like char (there are only 255 of them)). Then an `array` would be best.

Answer (score 1):

Hashing and `unordered_map` mean normally the same in this context.

Recommendation: Use a `std::unordered_map`

There is no real limit. Most often it will be the available memory.

Of course limit is also given by available data types.